# How to compare two json object names in typescript or javascript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, angular8, angular14

I am trying to find the difference between two JSON object property name in typescript or JavaScript. When we comparing the two JSON object how to find the which group name object values is different. Example: From my code group name B6006 is different, So how to get that group name in JavaScript or typescript. If anyone knows please help to find the solutions.

app.component.ts:

```
jsonobj1 = [
    {
      group_name: 'A6006',
      one_group: ['C85000_ZK', 'C95000_Z'],
      selected: [],
      two_group: ['FPC6516_A'],
    },
    {
      group_name: 'B6006',
      one_group: ['Z6800_BB', 'G6800_D'],
      selected: [],
      two_group: ['P6516_AB'],
    },
  ];
  jsonobj2 = [
    {
      group_name: 'A6006',
      one_group: ['C22000_ZK', 'C44000_Z'],
      selected: [],
      two_group: ['FPC9916_A'],
    },
    {
      group_name: 'B6006',
      one_group: ['Z6800_BB', 'G9900_D'],
      selected: [],
      two_group: ['P6516_AB'],
    },
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    if (JSON.stringify(this.jsonobj1) === JSON.stringify(this.jsonobj2)) {
      console.log('Both json object is same');
    } else {
       console.log('Both json object is not same. This'+propertyname????????+ 'value are different');
      
    }
  }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dbbfud?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Comment: @AshutoshVaish: No, Actually i am trying to get the group name

Comment: In what way "group name B6006 is different" that group A6006 isn't?

Comment: @ITgoldman: one_group and two_group values are different from group name B6006

Comment: But A6006 also has different one_group and two_group?